# Active Admin doesn't support activesupport 4.0.4 for Rails 4.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

As per documentation of Active Admin, I have include it in Gemfile as

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
```

But, when I bundle it, it give me errors as [image]

How to fix this issues ??

Comment: I have already updated the bundle but still its giving me same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try just tracking master for rails 4

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
```

Also, I don't think the newest version of `activeadmin` uses [`meta_search`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search) but instead is using [`ransack`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), check out this [pull request](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1979)

So, I would just get rid of `gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'` as well

Hope this helps!